# Using WITH FUNCTION in Oracle FOR LOOP CURSOR

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition.

For various reasons, our core database devs write almost everything using procedures and not functions.

I thought it would be fun to wrap a procedure or two into a function that returns the one or two data items we need in our SQL.

Instead of creating a regular function like a normal person would do, I found that I could declare functions using the WITH statement right in my SQL.

This works great as I'll show in my first example below, but when I try to use it in a FOR LOOP cursor it gives me an ORA-06550 error (missing keyword) right after the WITH keyword.

**Working SQL**

```sql
with
    function foobar(in_txt1 varchar2, in_txt2 varchar2) return varchar2 as
    begin
        return in_txt1 || in_txt2;
    end foobar;
select foobar('foo','bar') mytxt from dual;
```

**Broken SQL**

```sql
begin
    for cur in (
        with
            function foobar(in_txt1 varchar2, in_txt2 varchar2) return varchar2 as
            begin
                return in_txt1 || in_txt2;
            end foobar;
        select foobar('foo','bar') mytxt from dual
    )
    loop
        dbms_ouput.put_line(cur.mytxt);
    end loop;
end;
```

Oracle SQL Developer doesn't seem show any errors before I run the code. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Yes, I know that I could just run the procedure inside the loop, but this is more for a learning experience rather than production code.

Edit: It works if I use dynamic SQL, but that's not something I like to use. I think this just isn't supported at this time. I'll close this question if others agree this can't be done yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Oracle doesn't support this function currently - https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1#plsql-support. You can use dynamic SQL for the same.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Thank you for pointing this out. I did search for a while but I guess I couldn't find the right set of search terms. I really don't like using dynamic SQL, so I guess this has no answer yet.

Comment: If you want similar performance, build the function in isolation but with the UDF pragma, which lets the engine know you'll be calling it from SQL.  This will give the same efficiency as declaring it inline